# How to setup nginx laravel + vue cli project

Tags: laravel, ubuntu, nginx, vue.js

Hi I'm create laravel for BackOffice and Api for frontend.

In frontend I use vuejs.

How to setup nginx

- if find path /admin -> enter to laravelproject
- if find path /api -> enter to laravel project
- else just enter in vue project

Here Is what I use now

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;

    root /var/www/html;

    index index.html index.php  index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name localhost;

    location / {
        // Here is working fine run index.html ( vue )
        try_files $uri $uri/ = /index.html;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
      // setup php version
      include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;

      fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
   }

    location  /api {
        // I want to go in laravel path here. It's not working 
         root /var/www/html/serverside/public;
         try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    location  /admin {
        // I want to go in laravel path here.It's not working 
         root /var/www/html/serverside/public;
         try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

}
```

Here is my folder structure

```
/var/www/html/serverside/laravelproject ( in serverside laravel project locate here )
/var/www/html/index.html ( Here is vue js )
```

***** **UPDATE** *****

Here is my laravel.conf

```
server {
    listen 80;
    root /var/www/html/serverside/public;
    index  index.php index.html index.htm;
    server_name  localhost;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;        
    }


    location ~ \.php$ {
       include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
       fastcgi_pass             unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
       fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    }

}
```

nginx error.log show 
/`etc/nginx/sites-enabled/laravel.conf" failed (40: Too many levels of symbolic links) in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:`62

Comment: It's not working because `location ~ \.php$` block inherits `root /var/www/html;`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Minimum nginx vhost for laravel is sth like this,in ubuntu server correct place for this vhost is /etc/ngixt/sites-available.

```
#laravel.conf
server {
    listen 80;
    root /var/www/html/project_name/public;
    index  index.php index.html index.htm;
    server_name  api.example.com www.api.example.com;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;        
    }


    location ~ \.php$ {
       include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
       fastcgi_pass             unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
       fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    }

}
```

Minimum nginx vhost for vuejs is sth like this and you can use forever of pm2 to run your vue js app in perticular port like 8080,8081,... for proxy pass

```
#vue.conf
server {
  listen 80;
  index index.html;
  server_name example.com www.example.com;

  location / {
      proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
  }
}
```

Don't forget to generate symlink in sites enabled

```
# ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/laravel.conf /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/
# ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/vue.conf /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/
# service ntinx -t
# service nginx restart
```

Additionally you can add ssl  configurations and much more,

Comment: Job for nginx.service failed because the control process exited with error code.

I cant run service nginx restart  /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/laravel.conf" failed (40: Too many levels of symbolic links)

Comment: please send me log, this is not sufficient to figure out problem. cat /var/log/nginx/error.log  and send me log

Comment: /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/laravel.conf" failed (40: Too many levels of symbolic links) in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:62

Comment: I add laravel.conf and log into my question

Comment: error log clearly says that Too many levels of symbolic links, same vhost file is enabled multiple times in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/ fix that issue

Answer (score 0):

**if someone have this message error:**

Job for nginx.service failed because the control process exited with error code. I cant run service nginx restart /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/laravel.conf" failed (40: Too many levels of symbolic links)

The reason because the file link can not link the same file

**example** : ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/laravel.conf /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/

it will show this message error

please link file by using this command

**/etc/nginx/sites-available/{fileName} /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/**